# css animation when button get active not working

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to make a css animation for button.
Unfortunately not successful.

Please provide a example

visit http://osvaldas.info/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly and click demo button and check animation, that what i want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just learn css3 today, and after 20 minutes messing around, I think I have what you want. All the core code comes from the source code of your link page, I just tried to patch the missing ones, and I have to say this post improves me as well, cheers!

Here's the css part, the html structure is only one `<a href="#">Hit Me</a>`:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: aliceblue;
  background: #08a8e6;
  position: relative;
}

a:active::after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #08a8e6;
  animation: expand .25s ease, fade-out 0.25s linear;
}

@keyframes expand {
  from {transform: scale(1)}
  to {transform: scale(2)}
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  from {opacity: 1}
  to {opacity: 0}
}
```

Here's the [**demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaGWzj)

Although I just find out that my approach seems not perfect(same as your original page), you have to hold your mouse key down for a little while otherwise the animation will stop, hope other people can improve this.

Comment: Great! Problem is solved . thanks Brother : )